# Trying to see if N and its 2N exists within a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, math

Im doing a question where I am tasked iwth finding out if N and 2N are in a list. this is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def checkIfExist(self, arr: List[int]) -> bool:
        i = 0
        for number in arr:
            if number*2 in arr:
                return True
```

For some reason it returns true with this input:

```
[-2,0,10,-19,4,6,-8]
```

Why is this happening? Shouldnt it return False?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because `0 in arr` and `2*0 in arr` as well. So if you consider `0` special, you should special case it via `if number and 2*number in arr:`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that 2N of zero is also zero so it only needs to be in the list once in order for the function to return true.

You should make a special check for that edge case. Just make sure you have at least two zeroes in order to consider that both 0 and 2*0  (N and 2*N) are in the list as separate items.

for example:

```
def has2N(a):
    return any(N for N in a if 2*N in a) or a.count(0) > 1
```